# Unity IAP Unavaliable Product Google Play Store

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am having trouble with Unity IAP. I have an alpha release of my project in play store. I have setup iap on the store and have activated unity iap through the services on the editor by providing the correct service API key. The problem is that I cannot initialize the iap on my android build.

1. My IAP setup on the developer console:
   [image: Here]
2. Error I get on logcat:
   [image: Here]
3. Code for initialization:

   ```
   void Start() {
       if (!IsInitialized()) {
           var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
           builder.AddProduct("test_product", ProductType.Consumable);

           UnityPurchasing.Initialize(this, builder);
       }
   }

   public void OnInitialized(IStoreController controller, IExtensionProvider extensions) {
       Debug.Log("OnInitialized: PASS");
       storeController = controller;
       storeExtension = extensions;
   }

   public void OnInitializeFailed(InitializationFailureReason error) {
       Debug.LogError("OnInitializeFailed InitializationFailureReason: " + error);
   }
   ```

Comment: You need to register your products to the store you are using.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'register'? @captainCrazy

Comment: This kind of thing.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPGoogleConfiguration.html
The store (Google or Apple or whatever) needs to be aware of your products, it's not enough initializing them only on the Unity side.

Comment: Here is my product register on the store : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bj3z.png